# Why when i Exit application, Intent to other URI is getting close too?

Tags: android, android-intent

when i try to open dilar and after it close the application, everthing is closed
even the dialer.

```
        callBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String uri = "tel:" + userDetails.getNumber().trim() ;
             Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse(uri));
             callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             startActivity(callIntent);


            Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
             intent.setClass(QuickActivity.this, com.example.attention.AlertMsg.class);
             intent.putExtra("isExit", true);
             startActivity(intent);


        finish();


        }
    });
```

I the AlertMsg is my main activity, for exit i put the following code in AlertMsg

```
        if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("isExit", false))
    {
        if(mp!=null)
        {
            mp.stop();
        }
        finish();
    }
```

AnyOne have idea how can i open the dialer independent (will not be close if the app exits)and exit app activities?

Comment: in android 4.0.3 it works fine,
but in android 2.3.3 it dosent go to the dialer...

Comment: What i did was to do the dial action from the main activiy.
i sent intent with putExra string called "Dial".
and did: if(getIntent.getStringExtra("Dial").equals("Dial")
{
// Open Dialer here
finish();
}